# If $X$ is the union of contractible open subsets $A$ and $B$ then all cup products of positive dimensional classes in $H*(X;R)$ are zero.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The problem asks to use the cup product $H^k(X,A;R) \times H^l(X,B;R) \rightarrow H^{k+l}(X,A \cup B;R)$ to show that if $X$ is the union of contractible open subsets $A$ and $B$ then all cup products of positive dimensional classes in the cohomology ring $H^*(X;R)$ are zero.

I use the long exact sequence of the pairs $(X,A)$ and $(X,B)$ to conclude that $H^n(X,A;R)\simeq H^n(X;R) \simeq H^n(X,B;R)$ for $n > 0$. Since $A \cup B = X$, the cup product $H^k(X,A;R) \times H^l(X,B;R) \rightarrow H^{k+l}(X,A \cup B;R)$ will always be zero.

> I am having trouble justifying that taking the cup product in $H^k(X,A;R) \times H^l(X,B;R)$ is the same as taking the cup product in $H^k(X;R) \times H^l(X;R)$. I'm pretty sure this is true due to the isomorphism but can't show it.

Comment: Try taking relative cup products $H^*(X,A)\otimes H^*(X,B)\rightarrow H^*(X,A\cup B)=0$.

Comment: @Tyrone That is what I was doing already is it not ?

Comment: The relative cup products enjoy the same naturality as regular cup products. If $\iota:(X;A,B)\rightarrow (X;A\cup B,B)$ is the map of triads induced by inclusion then the relative cup product of $x\in H^*(X,A)$ and $y\in H^*(X,B)$ satisfies $\iota^*(x\cup y)=(\iota^*x)\cup (\iota^*y)\in H^*(X,A\cup B)$. Combine this with the naturality of the isomorphisms $H^*(X)\cong H^(X,A)$ and $H^*(X)\cong H^*(X,B)$ with respect to the exact sequences beloning to each pair $(X,A)$, $(X,B)$ and $(X,A\cup B)$ and you have the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that taking the cup product in $H^k(X,A;R) \times H^l(X,B;R)$ is the same as the cup product in $H^k(X;R) \times H^l(X;R)$ can be expressed mathematically as the commutativity of
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^k(X,A;R) \otimes H^l(X,B;R) @>{\smile}>> H^{k+l}(X,A\cup B;R)\\
@VV{\approx}V @VV{0}V \\
H^k(X;R) \otimes H^l(X;R) @>{\smile}>> H^{k+l}(X;R)
\end{CD}
$$
You can easily show directly that this diagram commutes (if there's anything to show at all). Alternatively, you can see it as a special case of the fact that the cup product behaves well with respect to continuous maps. In particular, when $f: Y \to X$ is a map of spaces such that $f(C)\subseteq A$ and $f(D) \subseteq B$, where $A,B,C,D$ are arbitrary subsets, then we have a commuting diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^k(X,A;R) \otimes H^l(X,B;R) @>{\smile}>> H^{k+l}(X,A\cup B;R)\\
@VV{f^* \otimes\ f^*}V @VV{f^*}V \\
H^k(Y,C;R) \otimes H^l(Y,D;R) @>{\smile}>> H^{k+l}(Y,C\cup D;R)
\end{CD}
$$
for all $k,l$.

Comment: This is a good answer, and the first diagram is exactly what I have been working on. But the part I'm having trouble with is what you've claimed there may be nothing to show at all, i.e. showing the diagram commutes. It's not clear to me why $\smile\Phi =0$, where I've used $\Phi$ to denote the isomorphism in the first diagram.

Comment: Don't let yourself get confused by the $0$ in the diagram. I should probably have written $j^*$ there, where $j: C_n(X) \to C_n(X,A∪B)$ is the canonical chain map dividing by $C_n(A∪B)$. It just happens to be zero here because the group in the upper right is zero. To show commutativity, just start with the classes of cocycles $\varphi\in C^k(X,A)$ and $\psi\in C^l(X,B)$, and recall that these can simply be treated as maps from the chain group $C_n(X)$ to $R$ which vanish on simplices in $A$ or $B$, respectively.

Comment: Then the upper $⌣$ sends $[\varphi]⊗[\psi]$ to the class of some cocycle $ρ$ which is cohomologous to $φ⌣ψ$ and which vanishes on $A\cup B$. The righ-hand map now maps this to $[\rho]$ itself. Since basically all downward maps send a class to itself, commutativity follows.

Comment: Its because of this triviality of $j^*$ that I wondered if there was anything to show at all. It is more or less trivial, but of course this is easy to say if some fact is already clear to oneself :-) Tell me if you need any further assistance.